# Is my proof for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac3{n+1}$ wrong?

Tags: calculus, limits

To calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac3{n+1}$ I do:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac3{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac3\infty=0$$
but my teacher is not convinced so how can I do??

Comment: Show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that for $n\geq N$ we have $|3/(n+1)-0|<\epsilon$.

Comment: i don't know that technique

Comment: Look at the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=l$ in your textbook.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_Definition) basically we're saying that for any arbitrary small number $\epsilon$ I can find a number $N$ for which all elements of your sequence after $N$ are closer than $\epsilon$ to zero.

Comment: the problem is that i can't do that technique for the moment, maybe here is a better technique: lim n→oo 3/n+1=lim x→oo 3/x = 0 i used new number x which will also tend to infinity

Comment: The way you've presented this (in the OP) suggests that you don't understand how to take the limit. That might be why you teacher isn't satisfied with it.

Comment: This is a high school "proof".

Comment: everyone i found how to do it: lim n→oo 3/n+1 = 3/oo = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O.K. A proof without $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ can it be as follow. 
Assuming that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ we have that 
$0<\frac{3}{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n>50$ for example (since we use n large this no matter) so $\lim \frac{3}{n+1}\leq \lim\frac{1}{n}=0$ but $\frac{3}{n+1}>0$ so $\lim\frac{3}{n+1}\geq 0$ i.e. $\lim\frac{3}{n+1}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \ell$ means precisely the same thing as $\lim_{n \rightarrow 0^+} f(1/x) = \ell$. In this case, $f(x) = 3/(x + 1)$ and $f(1/x) = 3x/(x + 1)$. Because the latter function is continuous at $0$, we can evaluate the limit by evaluating the function. In less words,
 $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{n + 1} ~ = ~ \lim_{n \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{3n}{n + 1} ~ = ~ 0$$